# error "Undefinded method "load_defaults" " when trying to deploy app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler

I'm new to ruby and rails programming, so I've been following the railstutorial.org online book, and came across an obstacle that I haven't been able to solve for a couple hours:

After running "git push heroku master" in Bash, I get the following:

```
Counting objects: 90, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
Writing objects: 100% (90/90), 21.30 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 90 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:             Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.14.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Installing i18n 0.8.1
remote:        Installing rake 12.0.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Installing minitest 5.10.1
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.3
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.1
remote:        Installing nio4r 1.2.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.4
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.4
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
remote:        Installing puma 3.4.0 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.23
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.7
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.3
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.7.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.5
remote:        Installing globalid 0.4.0
remote:        Installing activemodel 5.0.1
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.4.1
remote:        Installing activejob 5.0.1
remote:        Installing activerecord 5.0.1
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.2
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing actionview 5.0.1
remote:        Installing actionpack 5.0.1
remote:        Installing actionmailer 5.0.1
remote:        Installing actioncable 5.0.1
remote:        Installing railties 5.0.1
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Installing rails 5.0.1
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 53 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (25.85s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v6.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     NoMethodError: undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fe95df68030>
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:HelloApp>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:102:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: rake aborted!
remote: NoMethodError: undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fe95df68030>
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:HelloApp>'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
remote: /tmp/build_9d66aec07e51cd554443c45d6ce07bca/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:757:in `rake'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:132:in `log'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:778:in `allow_git'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:103:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:92:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:57:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:55:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:132:in `log'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to cryptic-bastion-24389.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/cryptic-bastion-24389.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/cryptic-bastion-24389.git'
```

Noting the message:

```
remote: -----> Installing node-v6.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     NoMethodError: undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fe95df68030>
```

I looked up code in my files to see where "load_defaults" was being called and it seems to be from the file application.rb in my app's directory > config

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module HelloApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

However I have tried looking up the same error message and executing all suggested messages and I still haven't been able to push my app to Heroku, always getting the exact same error again. I'm still not sure what 
"remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string" even means yet.

I assume the whole problem is something related to my gems so here is the content of my Gemfile file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.1'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Yes I have executed bundle install --without production before anything. No luck from the beginning. AFAIK I followed all the steps in the first chapter of railstutorial book.

Output of either "bundle exec install"

```
install: missing file operand
```

and "bundle exec install?",

```
sh: 1: install?: not found
```

Comment: what response do you get when you run the command: bundle exec install?

Comment: `bundle exec install
install: missing file operand`
 and/or...
`bundle exec install? :
sh: 1: install?: not found`

Comment: Put that information into your question rather than in a comment where you would have put it if you'd included it initially, formatting appropriately for readability and without "edited" or "updated" tags. That allows us to read the question and get everything we need to know, rather than force us to read every comment and try to piece it together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first I'll apologize for going as far as to having to make a question and finding the *solution* by myself 20 mins later.

While I'm not sure exactly **what** was malfunctioning, I did narrow it down to differing  versions of Rails and other gems, as I was using old specific versions that said book , railstutorial.org/book , indicated me to use.

What I did was use all the default gems given by the command **rails new**  for my Gemfile, without specifiying versions or anything other than the production group for the pg gem.

Gemfile code that fixed it:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end


group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Your lesson learned (should be): Never add or change a gem without using the command: bundle or bundle install  By saying you don't know what malfunctioned you're indicating you did not learn that dependencies and conflicts in gems will throw errors. Learn how to use bundler.

Comment: I'm confident in what I learned from this but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 15):

Go to `config/application.rb` then comment this code `config.load_defaults 5.1` out like this: `#config.load_defaults 5.1` (insert a "#") 
or you can just remove this code, but in case you might need this later so it's better to just comment it out.

I had same issue, commented it out and it worked fine.

Comment: do you also have an explanation, why this line causes the problem?

Comment: Just gonna point out that by doing this you're probably skipping loading some default options that maybe you will have to define somewhere else. When dealing with this I learned that I was using a different version than the one I was passing to load_defaults, so rather than just skipping this the `load_defaults`, as I was (and still am to an extent) oblivious to its purpose, I realized that's not what needed to be fixed, but my gems. It's important to know the implications of a given solution.

Comment: Bad advise! Please don't advise commenting framework generated code without even knowing what it does.You are probably using git - with a meaningful commit message you don't need to comment any line, but can  delete it because it stays in your history and has a description why you removed it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, just try bundle and report the results. If it reports you're missing bundler, then run gem install bundler

Comment: the command bundle packages everything you need to run remotely (and locally, too) It makes sure all the dependencies are met. Dependencies may be different for remote app. Running just the word bundle will give you some good feedback.

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to use `/usr/lib` gems folder.
You can see the gems folders using it:

`bundle show --paths`

When I had installed all Gems on `./vendor/bundle` on my project folder, it worked fine.

`bundle install --path vendor/bundle`

Answer (score 1):

You had Rails 5.0.1 installed. `load_defaults` wasn't introduced until 5.1.7.

https://apidock.com/rails/v5.1.7/Rails/Application/Configuration/load_defaults