# error when starting rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.4, ubuntu-18.04

I get the error below when I try to start my rails console,

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000055af3aee4550> (NoMethodError)
        from /home/alizain/www/WorkStationMetrices/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
        from /home/alizain/www/WorkStationMetrices/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:WorkstationMetrics>'
        from /home/alizain/www/WorkStationMetrices/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/alizain/www/WorkStationMetrices/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
        from /home/alizain/www/WorkStationMetrices/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
        from /home/alizain/www/WorkStationMetrices/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
        from /home/alizain/www/WorkStationMetrices/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
        from /home/alizain/www/WorkStationMetrices/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
        from /home/alizain/www/WorkStationMetrices/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
        from /home/alizain/www/WorkStationMetrices/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error stack given , it seems like you are having issues with loading configuration during application loading.

Below mentioned link also addresses the same issue.

[error "Undefinded method "load_defaults" " when trying to deploy app on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813749/error-undefinded-method-load-defaults-when-trying-to-deploy-app-on-heroku)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I have given try to that link, but this error occurs whenever i run rails c